# Simple Json connection not working

Tags: json, kendo-ui, datasource

I am trying to familiarise myself with the kendo ui dataSource, I have never before used JSON and have constructed the following using your documentation:

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kendo UI Web</title>
        <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "people.json",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: myDataSource,
                    columns: [
                    {
                        field: "firstName",
                        title: "First Name"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "lastName",
                        title: "Last Name"
                }]
            });

        });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Json File:

```
{
    "people": [
        { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
        { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

The grid doesn't load any data, all I see are the headers.

I have tried this using simply HTML and a JSON file, I have also tried this in Visual Studio.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSON the data transmitted is not an `array` but an `object` so you need to specify where in that object the data is stored, making possible to KendoUI DataSource finding it. This is specified using [`schema.data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data)

Your datasource should be:

```
var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url     : "people.json",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema   : {
        data: "people"
    }
});
```

Comment: Really strange, I've copied your code and just added `, schema : { data : "people" }` and worked perfectly well.

Comment: Should this be working with just a .html and .json file? Does this have any hosting requirements to work? I've tried within visual studio also.

Comment: You just need in the same folder the html and the json (and obviously the 4 Kendo UI files that you are including).

Comment: Check it here (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/bANPT/) the only difference is that I'm not requesting the data from a file but using JSON object in memory but if you remove the `schema.data` you will see that it doesn't show any data.

Comment: If I replace my 'transport' section with the 'data' section from yours it works fine, very odd. The transport part must be the issue.

Comment: The transport is ok since I've tried also with it in my PC. Do you have the file `people.json` in the same folder than the html? Did you try opening it from your browser? Did you use the same content that you pasted in the post?

Comment: It appears Google Chrome was the issue, installed firefox and seems to work fine. Your answer was correct all along, thank you for the help.