# JSON databinding for kendo ui grid with angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, kendo-ui-grid

I am using kendo UI grid with angular and I want to bind grid using json file (model.json) stored in the root directory as the index.html (I am using visual studio 2013 and web empty project template). My javascript controller is stored in Scripts/app/ directory.
This is my json file:

```
{
"model":  [
    {
        "RowNumber": "1",
        "AccountNo": "10236",
        "PostingDate": "20.01.2015",
        "AmountDebit": "1800.0",
        "AmountCredit": "1500.0",
        "Balance": "300.0",
        "Description": "Neki Opis"
    },
    {
        "RowNumber": "2",
        "AccountNo": "10648",
        "PostingDate": "26.01.2015",
        "AmountDebit": "3000.0",
        "AmountCredit": "1700.0",
        "Balance": "1300.0",
        "Description": "skafiskafnjak"
    },
    {
        "RowNumber": "3",
        "AccountNo": "10700",
        "PostingDate": "22.01.2015",
        "AmountDebit": "2900.0",
        "AmountCredit": "1800.0",
        "Balance": "1100.0",
        "Description": "knjizenje"
    },
    {
        "RowNumber": "4",
        "AccountNo": "10810",
        "PostingDate": "24.01.2015",
        "AmountDebit": "3800.0",
        "AmountCredit": "1400.0",
        "Balance": "2400.0",
        "Description": "hlabuka"
    },
    {
        "RowNumber": "5",
        "AccountNo": "10101",
        "PostingDate": "29.01.2015",
        "AmountDebit": "3800.0",
        "AmountCredit": "1500.0",
        "Balance": "2300.0",
        "Description": "Neki Opis"
    },
    {
        "RowNumber": "6",
        "AccountNo": "10364",
        "PostingDate": "25.01.2015",
        "AmountDebit": "4300.0",
        "AmountCredit": "1800.0",
        "Balance": "2500.0",
        "Description": "TestNova"
    }
]
}
```

This is my controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("generalledgerController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.gridMaster = {
        dataSource: {
            dataType: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "model.json"
            },
            schema: {
                data: "model"
            }
        },
        selectable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSize: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "RowNumber", title: "R. Br.", width: "50px", template: '<div style="text-align:center;">#= kendo.toString(RowNumber) #</div>' },
            { field: "AccountNo", title: " Br. Knjiženja", width: "77px", template: '<div style="text-align:left;">#= kendo.toString(AccountNo) #</div>' },
            { field: "PostingDate", title: "Datum", width: "70px" },
            { field: "Description", title: "Opis", width: "170px" },
            { field: "AmountCredit", title: "Duguje", width: "80px", template: '<div style="text-align:right;">#= kendo.toString(AmountCredit, "n2") #</div>' },
            { field: "AmountDebit", title: "Potražuje", width: "80px", template: '<div style="text-align:right;">#= kendo.toString(AmountDebit, "n2") #</div>' },
            { field: "Balance", title: "Saldo", width: "80px", template: '<div style="text-align:right;">#= kendo.toString(Balance, "n2") #</div>' }
        ],
        toolbar: ["create"]
    };
});

})();
```

This is my html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/metisMenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/bootstrap-theme.css.map">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/Site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.metro.min.css">
    <link href="content/generalledger.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app/generalledgercontroller.js"></script>
    <title>App</title>
</head>


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="generalledgerController">
    <div id="wrapper" class="active">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <h3 class="navbar-brand" style="font-family: 'Lato', calibri;width: 100%;margin: 0;left: 3%;color: grey;font-size: 24px;font-weight: 400">Logo</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="padding-right: 20px">
                <ul class=" nav navbar-nav" style="padding-left:20px"></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div>
                        <div class="divH3Style">
                            <h3 class="h3LabelForm">General Ledger</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tabstrip" class="k-tabstrip-wrapper" kendo-tab-strip="tabStrip">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Overview</li>
                                <li>Update</li>
                            </ul>
                            <div id="tabstrip-1">
                                <div kendo-grid k-options="gridMaster" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tabstrip-2">
                            <!-- fields for input/update data -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The grid doesn't load any data, all I see are the headers.
I watched all the relevant links to this problem:
[Simple Json connection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979484/simple-json-connection-not-working), [Binding a kendo ui grid to a json file without generating the grid in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631689/binding-a-kendo-ui-grid-to-a-json-file-without-generating-the-grid-in-code), http://www.telerik.com/forums/simple-json-databinding...
Any help would be appreciated.